# Is htaccess secure enought to whitelist clients IPs?

Tags: access-control, known-vulnerabilities, apache, ip, whitelist

I'm using **.htaccess** to control source IP of connections to my web application. My configuration looks more or less like this:

> order deny,allow
>
> deny from all
>
> allow from X.Y.Z.Q

These days we can trust less and less things, every days some commonly used technique is found to be vulnerable. So I started to ask myself questions:

1. **Is this method really save and sufficient?**
2. **Should I employ some additional mechanism to protect my web-app better?**

I am using Apache 2.2.24 and PHP 5.4.17 in Fast-CGI mode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is sufficient to protect against Apache serving this directory, but a configuration error may disable this:

- If your main Apache configuration contains `AllowOverride None` (or similar), then `.htaccess` files are ignored. Thus your IP whitelist does not apply. Depending on the hostname or directory, different configuration might be set.
- If you have `Satisfy any` set (not default) and a client is authenticated with the server, then it is still granted access.

Furthermore, there are other attack surfaces that may bypass your IP restrictions:

- On a shared webserver, it might be possible for other users of the server to access your files over the filesystem, bypassing Apache.
- If your webapp does not use HTTPS, it is already vulnerable to sniffing and MitM attacks.
- Your app could still be vulnerable to CSRF. If someone knows that a particular app is running on this host, (s)he could trick you into opening a page that exploits a CSRF vulnerability in your app (if any).

Suggestions:

- If this is a dedicated server for this webapp, configure the firewall to whitelist your IP addresses for this port. Remember to check your IPv6 configuration as well.
- Ensure that file permissions are correctly configured. Should any service (running as a different user that is not root) on your server be compromised, then your app should still be safe (providing there are no privilege escalation bugs).